# BcMath Subtracting big numbers + creating a while loop for the difference

Tags: php

I got a question how to round numbers of BCMath? And somehow this code doesn't work properly - cause when I remove the text it becomes xxx.00000 . I need really help on this one I got no idea how should it look like to make it working properly.

**Code**

```
    if (isset($_POST['licz'])) {
            $liczba_a='1111111111111111111';
            $liczba_b='1111111111111111100';
            echo $a = round(bcsub($liczba_a, $liczba_b)).'<br>';
            $diffcap = round($a);
            //secure 1

            $i = 0;
            $count = round($diffcap);
            $array= array();

            while ($i < $count) {
               echo 'array '.$b = bcadd($liczba_a, $i).'<br>';
               array_push($array, $b);
               ++$i;
            }
            var_dump($array);

    } else {
            echo "Wpisz liczby.";
    }
    ?>
```

**My output**

```
11 - this is the diff number
array 1111111111111111111
array 1111111111111111112
array 1111111111111111113
array 1111111111111111114
array 1111111111111111115
array 1111111111111111116
array 1111111111111111117
array 1111111111111111118
array 1111111111111111119
array 1111111111111111120
array 1111111111111111121
array(11) { [0]=> string(23) "1111111111111111111
" [1]=> string(23) "1111111111111111112
" [2]=> string(23) "1111111111111111113
" [3]=> string(23) "1111111111111111114
" [4]=> string(23) "1111111111111111115
" [5]=> string(23) "1111111111111111116
" [6]=> string(23) "1111111111111111117
" [7]=> string(23) "1111111111111111118
" [8]=> string(23) "1111111111111111119
" [9]=> string(23) "1111111111111111120
" [10]=> string(23) "1111111111111111121
" }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Assign operator has lower [precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than concatination.

```
echo 'array '.$b = bcadd($liczba_a, $i).'<br>';
                                       ^ it would be first operation.
                 ^ it would be second opration.
```

You should add parentheses

```
echo 'array '.($b = bcadd($liczba_a, $i)).'<br>';
```

But better to avoid double purpose operations.

```
$b = bcadd($liczba_a, $i);
echo 'array '. $b .'<br>';
```